# Check if an element is being observed, IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

Is there any way to determine if an element is being observed already?

```
if ( element /* is not being observed */ ) observer.observe(element)
```

Comment: No. The [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) doesn't have that ability.

Comment: @Ouroborus damn. alright. thanks for informing me

Comment: @oldboy it's possible

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev how?

Comment: Why do you need this? You can call multiple times observer.observe(elem)  and it will still be observed only once by this observer.

Comment: @Kaiido i need to monitor a single element in a group of elements that are to be monitored one by one in order to make constant calculations based on the "focused" element without always looping through the group of elements. FWIW, the group of elements might sometimes be in the hundreds and, in addition to this, the group might be duplicated multiple times to facilitate infinite scrolling -- wait a second -- i guess i could just apply it to each and every element and use `entry.target` to identify the "focused" element. hopefully, this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not currently seem to be a way to detect if an element is being observed. To over come this the simplest solution is to add a flag to an element when you attach the `Observer` to it. Then you can look for this flag in the future when you need to check if it has already been added.

```
element.dataset.libraryNameObserverType = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Monkey patch `observe()` and `disconnect()` methods.
When calling `observe()` collect DOM elements associated with particular observer in a `WeakSet` for the observer stored in `WeakMap`.
When calling `disconnect()` remove the observer from the map.

To get all elements observed collect all elements from the sets in the map.

Make sure your code executes at the very beginning.

Comment: im self-taught and that is one area where im lacking (i.e. manipulating properties of prototypes). can you provide a code example? and would i add it when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired?

Comment: Manipulating prototypes is generally considered a bad idea in modern JS. As it is a global change and you can not predict the effect it might have on different JS libraries

Comment: @DavidBradshaw your statement is exactly for JS libraries. that's totally right. I still consider OK to change prototypes in leaf projects (not reused, final). Since no libraries are allowed to monkey patch you can make sure your project is in control of monkeypatching